# Getting all continuous sub-arrays from a given array of integers

Tags: java, arrays

I want to find all the sub-arrays from a given array of integers. I used HashSet of ArrayList to store all the continuous combinations. But this hashset is not storing array elements properly and missing out some of the array elements. Also, the hashset is storing duplicate array elements.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SubArrays {

    public static int possibleSubArrays(int[] aray) {

        Set<ArrayList<Integer>> uniqueSubArrays= new HashSet<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < aray.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<Integer> subArrays = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int j = i; j < aray.length; j++) {
                subArrays.add(aray[j]);
                System.out.println("Creating Sub-Array: " + subArrays);
                uniqueSubArrays.add(subArrays);
                System.out.println("Entering elements in Set of array: " + uniqueSubArrays);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Array of sub-arrays:" + uniqueSubArrays);

        return uniqueSubArrays.size();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        int size = possibleSubArrays(array);
        System.out.println("Size of Unique Sub arrays is: " + size);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how we generate the `sub-arrays` of an array.
We need three nested loops to generate all the sub-arrays. First two loops for getting the starting and end index of the sub-arrays. And the third one to add all the elements of a particular sub-array to the `subArrays` list. And at the end of each `j`-th iteration, we need to add those `subArrays` list to the `uniqueSubArrays` set.

```java
        for (int i = 0; i < aray.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j < aray.length; j++)
            {
                ArrayList<Integer> subArrays = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int k = i; k <= j; k++)
                {
                    subArrays.add(aray[k]);
                    uniqueSubArrays.add(subArrays);
                }
                System.out.println(uniqueSubArrays);
            }
        }
```

For array: **[1,2,3,4]**
Sub-arrays:

```
[[1], [1, 2, 3], [2], [1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```